# Is there a way to relationship between two table which table one has 3 unique keys and table two has 2 unique keys in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I want to create relation between two tables, here's my table structure

**Table1**:

```
ID INT PrimaryKey AUTO_INCREMENT,
CountryCode INT UNIQUE,
Division VARCHAR(4) UNIQUE,
SubDivision VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
```

**Table2**:

```
ID INT PrimaryKey AUTO_INCREMENT,
CountryCode INT UNIQUE,
Division VARCHAR(4) UNIQUE,
ReportNo VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
```

**Table1**:

```
ID     |CountryCode       |Division      |SubDivision
-------+------------------+--------------+-----------
1      |IDN               |A             |A-1
2      |IDN               |B             |B-1
3      |IDN               |B             |B-2
```

**Table2**

```
ID     |CountryCode       |Division      |ReportNo
-------+------------------+--------------+-----------
1      |IDN               |A             |Re001
2      |IDN               |A             |Re002
3      |IDN               |B             |Re003
```

I want to create a relationship between those two tables which `table2 (CountryCode, Division)` refers to `table1 (CountryCode, Division)`.

So when I want to delete in table1 with CountryCode = IDN and Division = A, SQL will prompt error when table2 contains CountryCode = IDN and Division = A.

I had tried to create a relationship between those two tables, but SQL Server always throws this error:

> The column in table 'table1' do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Can anyone guide me how can I create a relationship between those two tables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` isn't SQL Server syntax. Do you use MySQL? You design also looks wrong in many places. May be you should have a table for each of country, division and subdivision with foreign keys to the "higher" table respectively. In the table for the report then use only a foreign key to subdivision.

Comment: Thank you for your correction and your suggestion. I'll try to rebuild my db design. (Y) :D

Comment: You can if you create an uniq index on your table1 on your columns CountryCode and Division, but the solution of GMB is the better if you can use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. SQL Server requires a unique constraint (or primary key constraint) on the target of a foreign key - and you have duplicates in the source table.

For this to work, you would need to have a separate table that references all possible `(CountryCode, Division)` combinations. Actually, your whole schema should be normalized into something like:

```
-- "top" table that stores the countries
create table countries (
    country_id int primary key
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the divisions
create table divisions (
    division_id int primary key,
    country_id int references countries(country_id),
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the subdivisions
-- this corresponds to "table1" in your question
create table subdivisions (
    subdivision_id int primary key,
    division_id int references divisions(division_id),
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the reports
-- this corresponds to "table2" in your question
create table reports (
    report_id int primary key,
    division_id references divisions(division_id),
    name varchar(100)
);
```

You can make the primary keys automatic by using `identity` columns (which is the SQL Server equivalent for MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`).

As an example, here is how you would generate the current output that you are showing for the subdivisions:

```
select 
    sd.id,
    c.name country,
    d.name division,
    sd.name subdivision
from subdivisions sd
inner join divisions d on d.division_id = sd.division_id
inner join countries c on c.country_id = d.country_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @gmb, I had learn something from you. And I'll implemented your suggestion.

Comment: but, if implemented as your design, how can I select out to get the result I wanted? because I face problem that I cannot loading form dynamic output as my db design.

Comment: @user8124226: I added an example query to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As GMB has answered you cannot do it in this way because of the duplicates. GMB's answer is the best way to solving your problem. If for some reason you cannot follow his advice then maybe my answer would help.

You could use a composite primary key on the columns CountryCode, Division, SubDivision. Then add subdivision to Table2. And then reference this primary key in the foreignkey restraint. (notice that my example throws an error on purpose to show that the value cannot be deleted)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CountryCode CHAR(3) 
    , Division VARCHAR(4) 
    , SubDivision VARCHAR(10)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY(CountryCode, Division, SubDivision)
    )
INSERT INTO Table1(CountryCode, Division, SubDivision)
VALUES    ('IDN', 'A', 'A-1')
        , ('IDN', 'B', 'B-1')
        , ('IDN', 'B', 'B-2');

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
    , CountryCode CHAR(3) 
    , Division VARCHAR(4) 
    , SubDivision VARCHAR(10)
    , ReportNo VARCHAR(10) 
    , CONSTRAINT FK_CountryDivision FOREIGN KEY(CountryCode, Division, SubDivision) REFERENCES Table1(CountryCode, Division, SubDivision)
    );
INSERT INTO Table2(CountryCode, Division, SubDivision, ReportNo)
VALUES    ('IDN', 'A', 'A-1', 'Re001')
        , ('IDN', 'B', 'B-1', 'Re002')
        , ('IDN', 'B', 'B-2', 'Re003');

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Division = 'A';
```

Of course this change could add a whole set of new problems for instance when a report is for the whole division what should the subdivision value then be.

ps. i had to change up the example tables a bit because the values did not match, ie string values into an int column.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0287b/3/0)

Comment: Hi @8812269, thank you for your advise. I'll try again, I'll let you know if is possible in my design.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the all greats answer.

But in my design I can't doing this, because I has been wrong at the first time.

And the greats answer was from Mr. @10676716 @GMB.

```
-- "top" table that stores the countries
create table countries (
    country_id int primary key
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the divisions
create table divisions (
    division_id int primary key,
    country_id int references countries(country_id),
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the subdivisions
-- this corresponds to "table1" in your question
create table subdivisions (
    subdivision_id int primary key,
    division_id int references divisions(division_id),
    name varchar(100)
);

-- the table that stores the reports
-- this corresponds to "table2" in your question
create table reports (
    report_id int primary key,
    division_id references divisions(division_id),
    name varchar(100)
);
```

Thanks again Mr. GMB.